# graphql.org "/learn/queries/" Issue with Examples

Tags: graphql

Sorry in advance if this turns out to be such a simple question. I'm just starting out with GraphQL. I went here to learn about it:

https://graphql.org/learn/queries/

It's cool because the examples are in interactive editors. Under the Arguments subheading, for example, you can add `id` to the query, and then the output will contain `"id": "1000"`. What's throwing me, though, is that in the subsequent sections (e.g., Aliases) there's an argument `episode` that's used. But when I try and add `episode` to the query, it doesn't work, and it isn't in the "auto complete" list of attributes of a `hero`. It seems strange that you could use an argument to filter on something but not use that field in the query. See screenshot.

I totally understand this is a simple page showing trivial examples for the purpose of learning. Is it perhaps that there's just a bug in this documentation? Or is `episode` there and I'm just not understanding something?

Thanks!
-Brian[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query for `hero` is just a function that does something. Its arguments are completely made up by whoever wrote the query, and are not related to the properties of the object it returns. For example, if you have some e-commerce website, you could allow a search for all customers who have purchased a specific product like:

```
type Query {
  customersFromProductPurchased(productId: String!): [Customer]
}
```

and that doesn't mean that the `Customer` object is going to have a property called `productId`.

---

FWIW, the `hero` query returns a `Character` type. From just the autocomplete on that page, I can tell you that the type definition for `Character` looks like this:

```
type Character {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  friends: [Character]
  friendsConnection: FriendsConnection!
  appearsIn: [Episode]!
}
```